# Cant copy a 90GB file to a free space of 165GB

Tags: windows, filesystems, file-transfer

A `C:` partition have about 164 Gigabyte free space.

[image]

Id like to copy a file having 90GB from `X:\Software\Downloads\` to `C:\Intel\`

[image]

Unfortunately the copy fail because 164GB is not enougth space for a 90GB file, you need further 16.9 GB!

[image]

```
 Copy element

 On Intel exists not sufficient storage.
 16.9 GB are required, that this element can be copied.
 Delete or move files that enougth storage gets available.
 Intel
 Creationdate: 02.07.2018 08:29 (am)
        Repeat process         abort
  /\ less details
```

I am pretty sure that a 90GB file fits into 164GB free space.

Why is Windows calculation that wrong?

Comment: Please add an exact English translation of the error dialog. (use the [edit] button)

Comment: I knew by seeing the drives size so deleted previous comment

Comment: @gronostaj Done

Comment: Are all drives formatted as NTFS?

Comment: @spikey_richie No! `E:` has format FAT32, `K:` has format UDF, `X:` has format NTFS, `Z:` has no storage device.

Comment: And C: is C: NTFS?

Comment: Just a comment, but `C:` should be `NTFS` if you plan on copying something that large to it.

Comment: @Anaksunaman @LPChip `C:` is `NTFS`.

Comment: Have you tried an extraction into the C:\Intel folder? That is a compress file. Don't you want the files extracted? Or extract the files first then move/copy them into C:\Intel ?

Comment: @vssher Decompress would take about 1500GB. Since decompression is by-definition an explosion of the filesize. The resulting error-message would be like "1500gb data is to large for 165 gb space" what indeed make sense but is not the task here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the [ADS](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13667/Enumerating-Alternate-Data-Streams). Now it fits.